# Recommended fingering for "Hometown Glory" intro

Tags: piano, fingering

Ironically, I find the intro to Adele's Hometown Glory easier to play than the main song; what sounds like a standard 'indie' vamp is deceptively difficult for me (reminds me a Carl Czerny study), and Neil Cowley's voicing really makes it sound out for me.

**Is it just 2+5 and 1+4 all the way through? Does anyone have any recommendations?**

---

[image: Hometown Glory mm. 1-4]

Image is a screen capture of mm. 1-4 from http://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0105664.

---

(P.S. [This guy gets it wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3rmguW15C0)).

Answer (score 2):

I ran over this, and I don't find that using 4 is comfortable on the first chord.  I use 5-2 on the first sixth, and 3-1 on the following fifth.  Normally, in the second measure, I would finger it 5-2 and 4-1, but in this case I again use 3-1 on the Ab-F, since 3 is already on the F from the previous measure. In the fourth measure I use 4-2 and 3-1, again because the 3 is already on the F.  If your hands are too small to use 3 all the time on the F, then switch back and forth between 3 and 4 as necessary.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well; typically it is not comfortable or economical to separate 4 and 5 by more than 2 semitones.

Comment: Agreed. This is the best fingering.